# How can I selectively place line from File into List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to take a file with a format like:

```
# Comments
# More comments

1,foo,bar,1
1,foo,bar,2
21,foo,bar,8

end_of_file
```

and process it into a list like:

```
listing = [[1,'foo','bar',1], [1,'foo','bar',2], [21,'foo','bar',8]]
```

Currently, I'm running something similar to:

```
listing = [] 
with open('foo_file.cfg','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0].isDigit:
            listing.append(line)   #  i've also tried listing.append([line])
```

Obviously, I'm ending up with:

```
[['1,foo,bar,1'],['1,foo,bar,2'],['21,foo,bar,8']]
```

I know I can split the `line` by comma, rebuild a new list, then append the list to `listing.`  I'm definitely willing to do that if it's the proper way, but I thought their might be something cleaner.  I know the `csv` module would read the whole file into a proper format, but I'm not sure how it would deal with selectively removing certain data, such as the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way with `csv` module, which avoids explicitly accounting for some of the repetitive tasks (comma delimiter, new line, etc).

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

mystr = StringIO("""1,foo,bar,1
1,foo,bar,2
21,foo,bar,8""")

res = []

# replace mystr with open('file.csv', 'r')
with mystr as f:
    reader = filter(None, csv.reader(f))  # ignore empty lines
    for line in reader:
        if line[0].isdigit():
            res.append([int(line[0]), line[1], line[2], int(line[3])])

print(res)

[[1, 'foo', 'bar', 1],
 [1, 'foo', 'bar', 2],
 [21, 'foo', 'bar', 8]]
```

Comment: I like the look of this code.  Although below there are some slimmer options, I believe I prefer this one simply because once I have a better grasp of using the "filter,"  I'll have more flexibility in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in similar way without any module:

```
lst = []
for line in f:
    if not line.startswith('#') and line:
        lst.append([int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in line.split(',')])

print(lst)

# [[1, 'foo', 'bar', 1], [1, 'foo', 'bar', 2], [21, 'foo', 'bar', 8]]
```

Comment: This looks like it'd do what I'm looking for.  However, even though the logic looks simple, I haven't seen the structure within the append action before.  I'm going to have to look at that for a bit.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the last line is the only one you want to get rid of you could use `pandas.read_csv` using either `error_bad_lines=False` property or `skipfooter=1`

If it is necessary to loop through the lines of the file and check which line to import then I would just change the line that you append to the `listing` list to

```
listing.append(line.split(','))
```

Comment: I think listing.append(line.strip().split(',')) would get me closer, minus the proper data types...but I hadn't thought of this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One Pythonic approach is to use `itertools.dropwhile()` to ignore the first lines that meet a certain condition. Since `csv.reader` objects are iterator, this will no longer require reading the whole file once and then looping over the lines again for filtering them out. You can also remove the empty lines simply by checking the validation of the rows (`not(x)` in `lambda` function.)

```
import csv
from itertools import dropwhile

with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = dropwhile(lambda x: not(x) or x[0].startswith('#'), csv.reader(f))

# print(list(reader))
# [['1', 'foo', 'bar', '1'], ['1', 'foo', 'bar', '2'], ['21', 'foo', 'bar', '8']]
```

Comment: Oh man...that looks nice.  So the not(x) is what ignores the blank lines?

Comment: @pedwards Yes, it will drop the line if its logical not is valid (True).

Comment: So I've been reading the docs on itertools...some cool stuff.  I see the dropwhile and takewhile functions, but is there a way I'm not seeing to validate the data in the case of comments in the middle of the data?  Just thinking future uses.